# Java Game Physics - Determine intersection and collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection

My question can actually be broken down into two parts. The first, is what is a reasonable method for determining collision in a Java game? My second, is how to find the point of collision for use later?

Originally I was implementing a rudimentary collision system using a thread I found earlier with a simple method for finding a collision in a polygon. I have posted the code below. However as best I can tell, this will not show me the collision point, and I would have to do something separate to find it.

```
public boolean collisionDetection(int charX, int charY) {
    if(boundry == null)
        return false;

    int numVert = boundry.length;
    boolean ret = false;
    for(int i = 0, j = numVert - 1; i < numVert; j = i++) {
        if (((boundry[i].y >= charY) != (boundry[j].y >= charY)) && (charX <= (boundry[j].x -boundry[i].x) * (charY - boundry[i].y) / (boundry[j].y - boundry[i].y) + boundry[i].x)) {
             ret = !ret;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But I had a thought while working on this... Let us presume that I input my coordinates into the system as Points. I did them in order (e.g. point 1 -> point 2 -> point 3 -> point 1).

Knowing the points are in a connected order (e.g. they form the boundary of the object), is it then logical to say I could just use a number of line intersection methods to find if the character intersected with the border of my polygon? I know the characters current position, as well as the intended position.

Any thoughts, or if you have a suggestion a better implementation method?

Comment: `Knowing the points are in a connected order (e.g. they form the boundary of the object), is it then logical to say I could just use a number of line intersection methods to find if the character intersected with the border of my polygon?` If we're talking about two polygons in 2D, then yes.

Comment: And if the character can not be completely *inside* the polygon (or vice versa), then yes....

Comment: To answer - yes, 2D space. I have some concerns about being "inside" of the polygon, but I am sure I can deal with that later (or run a check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be doing either point to pint or box to box collision See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144107/android-opengl-es-collision-detection/25146311#25146311)

this explains two methods of collision detection. its in 3D but just drop the third axis and can be used for 2D. Hope this helps